Error Using Lightning Component to Activate Screen Flow
I have a screen flow that is activated using a lightning component that allows it to be activated via a global action. However, whenever I open the flow, I repeatedly get the following error message:

This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: 780666711)

Here are the error logs:
[NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/usa280.sfdc-lywfpd/auraFW/javascript/MTN2YUU1dmJ0Mm9HSzFyZTVFQk4xQUxYNjhRSmc0NVdXMEMtTDVwc1djalEyNTAuOC4zLTYuNC41/aura_prod.js:1068:112
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/usa280.sfdc-lywfpd/auraFW/javascript/MTN2YUU1dmJ0Mm9HSzFyZTVFQk4xQUxYNjhRSmc0NVdXMEMtTDVwc1djalEyNTAuOC4zLTYuNC41/aura_prod.js:1068:305
s()@https://static.lightning.force.com/usa280.sfdc-lywfpd/auraFW/javascript/MTN2YUU1dmJ0Mm9HSzFyZTVFQk4xQUxYNjhRSmc0NVdXMEMtTDVwc1djalEyNTAuOC4zLTYuNC41/aura_prod.js:49:53058
z.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/usa280.sfdc-lywfpd/auraFW/javascript/MTN2YUU1dmJ0Mm9HSzFyZTVFQk4xQUxYNjhRSmc0NVdXMEMtTDVwc1djalEyNTAuOC4zLTYuNC41/aura_prod.js:49:15166
z._fireStatusChange()@https://gulfcoastbc.lightning.force.com/components/flowruntime/flow.js:1:7615
z.handleInterviewScreen()@https://gulfcoastbc.lightning.force.com/components/flowruntime/flow.js:1:11685
e.Runtime._updateState()@https://gulfcoastbc.lightning.force.com/components/flowruntime/runtimeV3Lib.js:1:62432

Here is my lightning component:
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"  onstatuschange="{!c.handleStatusChange}" />
</aura:component>

Here is the controller:
({
init : function (component) {
// Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
var flow = component.find("flowData");
// In that component, start your flow. Reference the flow’s Unique Name.
flow.startFlow("Create_New_Intern_Task");
}
})

I am relatively new to using lightning components and aura, so I had help from the internet to create this global action/lightning component. I tried researching this specific error ID without any luck. The error logs are pretty much unreadable for me so I'm hoping someone may understand them, thanks!
